# stderr.write; printing strings

Tags: python, stderr

I am new to Python and having some trouble with the `stderr.write` function. I will try to illustrate it with code. Before I was doing this:

```
print "Unexpected error! File {0} could not be converted." .format(src)
```

But then I wanted to separate the error messages from other status messages so I tried doing this:

```
sys.stderr.write "Unexpected error! File %s could not be converted." src
```

But this results in error. I googled it as well but i couldn't find anything. Could anyone please help me out here. How can I print the string `src` using `stderr.write`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2.x:

```
sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error! File %s could not be converted." % src)
```

Or, in Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error! File {0} could not be converted.".format(src))
```

Comment: Also, consider using the logging module to log.

Comment: Of course logging is very usefull- but sometimes I it is better to log more details and print to stderr something different to mark that an error happened

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Python need to be followed by parens (`(...)`), optionally containing arguments, in order to be invoked.

```
sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error! File %s could not be converted.\n" % (src,))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stderr.write` is a function, so to call the function, you need to use parentheses around the argument:

```
In [1]: src='foo'

In [2]: sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error! File %s could not be converted."%src)
Unexpected error! File foo could not be converted.
```

Note that as of Python3, `print` is also a function and will also require parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed (,) and %:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("Unexpected error! File %s could not be converted." % src)
```